# Potential at a point at a distance from the centre of spherical shell with uniform surface charge density when point charge potential is abnormal?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge, potential

> So we assume that the electric potential of a point charge has the following form:
> $$
> V(r) = \frac{1}{4 \pi \varepsilon_0} \frac{q}{r^{1+\epsilon}}
> $$
> rather than the usual Coulomb potential.
> Now we have a spherical shell made up of these point charges, and the shell has uniform surface charge density $\sigma$.
> How do i find the potential $V(r)$ at a point $r$ from the centre of the shell of radius $R > r$? Assume that the superposition principle applies.

When we assume $\epsilon << 1$ and apply

$$
x^{1-\epsilon} \approx x(1-\epsilon \ln{x})
$$

the expressions $V(r)$ and $V(R)$ should then satisfy the approximation

$$
\frac{V(r)}{V(R)} \approx 1 + \frac{\epsilon}{2} \Bigl[ \frac{R}{r} \ln{\frac{R-r}{R+r}} + \ln{\frac{4R^2}{R^2-r^2}} \Bigr].
$$

First of all I thought the potential inside a charged electric shell was constant, but now that appears not to be the case, ostensibly because of the abnormal point charge potential.
So I tried integrating over the shell surface, but what I got doesn't seem to satisfy the approximation:

$$
V_{shell}(r) = \int_A \frac{1}{4 \pi \varepsilon_0} \frac{dq}{r^{1+\epsilon}} = \int_0^r \frac{1}{4 \pi \varepsilon_0} \frac{4 \pi r^2 \sigma}{r^{1+\epsilon}} dr \; = \; \frac{\sigma}{\varepsilon_0 (2-\epsilon)} \; r^{2-\epsilon}
$$

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have $V(r)=k r^{-1-\varepsilon}$, so we need to expand $x^{-1-\varepsilon}\sim x^{-1}-\frac{\log{x}}{x} \varepsilon$ for small $\varepsilon.$ So your quotient actually should be

\begin{align}
\frac{V(r)}{V(R)}&=\frac{r^{-1}-\frac{\log{r}}{r} \varepsilon}{R^{-1}-\frac{\log{R}}{R} \varepsilon}\sim \frac{R}{r}(1+\frac{\log{R}}{\log{r}})\varepsilon 
\end{align}
again for small $\varepsilon.$ But this is for a source charge at $r=0$ and this is not our case! Our charges are located at $r=R.$

So if integrate this over the surface of the shell (rememer the charge is at the surface, in R, thats $\sigma(r)=0$ end $\sigma(R)=\sigma$)

$$
V_{shell}(r) = \int_{Shell(0\to r)} \frac{1}{4 \pi \varepsilon_0} \frac{dq}{r^{1+\epsilon}}+\int_{Shell(r\to R)} \frac{1}{4 \pi \varepsilon_0} \frac{dq}{r^{1+\epsilon}} = \int_{Shell(r\to R)} \frac{1}{4 \pi \varepsilon_0} \frac{dq}{r^{1+\epsilon}} \\
=\int_{[0,\pi]\times[0,2\pi]} \int_r^R \frac{\sigma(r)}{4 \pi \varepsilon_0} r^{-1-\varepsilon}r^2 Sin(\phi)dr d\theta d\phi =\frac{1}{4 \pi \varepsilon_0} \int_{[0,\pi]\times[0,2\pi]}\frac{\sigma(r)r^{2-\varepsilon}}{2-\varepsilon}|_r^R \sin(\phi)d\theta d\phi \\
=\frac{\sigma}{4 \pi \varepsilon_0}\frac{R^{2-\varepsilon} }{2-\varepsilon}\int_{[0,\pi]\times[0,2\pi]}\sin(\phi)d\theta d\phi=\frac{\sigma}{4 \pi \varepsilon_0}\frac{R^{2-\varepsilon} }{2-\varepsilon} 4\pi =\frac{\sigma R^{2-\varepsilon }}{\varepsilon_0 (2-\varepsilon)}
$$